# Mail Merge from Http Request use a restful API

Tags: sql, ms-word, httprequest, mailmerge

In my project, I have a document in word and I need to use mail merge to fill the fields of the documents.  My problem is that my database is online on my domain and I can´t access these records from Word.  Can anyone help me?